# solving a second order difference equation, what are the steps?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, stability-in-odes

I've been given the following second order difference equation, and a set of questions following, but I'm not certain I've done it correctly, verification and hints are appreciated.

Given $x_{t+2}=-\frac{1}{2}x_{t+1}+\frac{3}{2} x_t$:

1. Write this as a system of first order difference equations and find all equilibria of the system $z_{t+1} = Az_t$.

For this problem I used a change of variable to say $y_{t+1}=-\frac{1}{2}y_t+\frac{3}{2} x_t$, and $y_t=x_{t+1}$,
which when I converted to a matrix (forthcoming in 2) and subtracted the identity matrix, produced infinitely many equilibria of the form x=y=c, where c is any real number.

2. Find the solution to this system, that is, find a matrix $D$ such that $z_{t+1} = D^tz_t$.

starting with the matrix from the system in 1, I have $$A=\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{2} \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$by subtracting λI from this I get
$$A-λI=\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{1}{2}-λ & \frac{3}{2} \\ 1 & -λ \end{bmatrix}$$
taking the determinant I have $λ^2+λ\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{2}=0$ which produces the roots $λ_1=1$ and $λ_2=\frac{-3}{2}$. The next step towards finding $D$ from my understanding is to plug the two values for lambda into $(A-λ_iI)v_i=0$ and solve for $v_1$ and $v_2$. At this point I get the following
$$v_1=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} v_2=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ \frac{-2}{3} \end{bmatrix}$$
Since these are linearly independent I get matrix $P$ composed of $v_1,v_2$,
$$P=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -\frac{2}{3} \end{bmatrix}$$ which I find the inverse of:
$$P^{-1}=\frac{-5}{3}\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{2}{3} & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
and finally our D matrix is
$$D=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{-3}{2}\end{bmatrix}$$
which from my understanding I can say that $z_{t+1} = PD^tP^{-1}z_t$.

3. (last part) Are the equilibria you found in part 1 stable?

I've been digging into the definition of stability for this question because my professor stated that the above eigenvalues are all I needed, and that if their moduli are 1 or greater then the equilibria are not asymptotically stable. I've also seen definitions involving epsilon neighborhoods, and limits of n as it goes to infinity. Based on the moduli statement my answer is no the equilibria are not stable($|\frac{-3}{2}|>|1|=1$), but I have no idea of the intuition behind this, since any initial conditions with $x_1=x_0=c$ will return c infinitely.

Comment: *Stability* refers to the tendency to attract towards an equilibrium when nearby. Hence, *instability* is the tendency to push away from an equilibrium **when nearby**. Sure, if you're sitting on the equilibrium value **exactly** you will stay there, but even the slightest nudge off of it will cause the values to slip away.

Comment: Think of a marble in a bowl. The equilibrium at the bottom is attracting (stable), as the marble will tend towards it from nearby. On the other hand, think of a marble balanced on the top of an inverted bowl. If it's not precisely at the equilibrium point on top, it will roll away, so we call such an equilibrium repelling (unstable).

Comment: to use the same marble analogy in this case we're using a flat surface and since the marble won't 'roll' to the same point ever, we'd call it unstable?